# Package folder not compiling?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I am working on a project in intelliJ idea (community edition), and I have two source folders: `engine` and `scripts`. I also have a test folder, called `Test`. I was having trouble earlier when  I tried to refactor some parts of this hierarchy earlier, and when I went to run it I got this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class engine.base.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: engine.base.Launcher
```

I think I know why it wasn't able to find the main class. When I went into the `out/production` folder to look, the `scripts` folder was the only folder that had been compiled. Does anybody know what is happening here, and how I can fix it?

Comment: try to clean and build project before running it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have properly [configured sources directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories). I.e. the parent of the `scripts` folder must be marked as a **source root**. Then when you run the [Application run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html), make sure the module where your main class is located is correctly specified.
Also make sure the project is properly built (you can run Build | Rebuild Project action to make sure all the sources are up to date compiled).